# Inference Labeled LDA/pLDA [Topic Modelling Toolbox]

Tags: scala, nlp, stanford-nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I have been trying to get through with the code for inference from trained labeled LDA model and pLDA using TMT toolbox(stanford nlp group).
I have gone through the examples provided in the following links: 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/ 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/

Here is the code I'm trying for labeled LDA inference

```
val modelPath = file("llda-cvb0-59ea15c7-31-61406081-75faccf7");

val model = LoadCVB0LabeledLDA(modelPath);`

val source = CSVFile("pubmed-oa-subset.csv") ~> IDColumn(1);

val text = {
  source ~>                              // read from the source file
  Column(4) ~>                           // select column containing text
  TokenizeWith(model.tokenizer.get)      //tokenize with model's tokenizer
 }

 val labels = {
  source ~>                              // read from the source file
  Column(2) ~>                           // take column two, the year
  TokenizeWith(WhitespaceTokenizer())     
 }

 val outputPath = file(modelPath, source.meta[java.io.File].getName.replaceAll(".csv",""));

 val dataset = LabeledLDADataset(text,labels,model.termIndex,model.topicIndex);

 val perDocTopicDistributions =  InferCVB0LabeledLDADocumentTopicDistributions(model, dataset);

 val perDocTermTopicDistributions =EstimateLabeledLDAPerWordTopicDistributions(model, dataset, perDocTopicDistributions);

 TSVFile(outputPath+"-word-topic-distributions.tsv").write({
  for ((terms,(dId,dists)) <- text.iterator zip perDocTermTopicDistributions.iterator) yield {
    require(terms.id == dId);
    (terms.id,
     for ((term,dist) <- (terms.value zip dists)) yield {
       term + " " + dist.activeIterator.map({
         case (topic,prob) => model.topicIndex.get.get(topic) + ":" + prob
       }).mkString(" ");
     });
  }
});
```

Error

`found   : scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[(String, Array[Double])]`
`required: Iterable[(String, scalala.collection.sparse.SparseArray[Double])]`
`EstimateLabeledLDAPerWordTopicDistributions(model, dataset, perDocTopicDistributions);`

I understand it's a type mismatch error. But I don't know how to resolve this for scala.
Basically I don't understand how should I extract the 
1. per doc topic distribution
2. per doc label distribution  after the output of the infer command.

Please help.
Same  in the case of pLDA.
I reach the  inference  command and after that clueless what to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

Scala type system is much more complex then Java one and understanding it will make you a better programmer. The problem lies here:

```
val perDocTermTopicDistributions =EstimateLabeledLDAPerWordTopicDistributions(model, dataset, perDocTopicDistributions);
```

because either model, or dataset, or perDocTopicDistributions are of type:

```
scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[(String, Array[Double])]
```

while EstimateLabeledLDAPerWordTopicDistributions.apply expects a

```
Iterable[(String, scalala.collection.sparse.SparseArray[Double])]
```

The best way to investigate this type errors is to look at the ScalaDoc (for example the one for tmt is there: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/api/#package ) and if you cannot find out where the problem lies easily, you should explicit the type of your variables inside your code like the following:

```
 val perDocTopicDistributions:LazyIterable[(String, Array[Double])] =  InferCVB0LabeledLDADocumentTopicDistributions(model, dataset)
```

If we look together to the javadoc of edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.stage:

```
def
EstimateLabeledLDAPerWordTopicDistributions (model: edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.model.llda.LabeledLDA[_, _, _], dataset: Iterable[LabeledLDADocumentParams], perDocTopicDistributions: Iterable[(String, SparseArray[Double])]): LazyIterable[(String, Array[SparseArray[Double]])]

def
InferCVB0LabeledLDADocumentTopicDistributions (model: CVB0LabeledLDA, dataset: Iterable[LabeledLDADocumentParams]): LazyIterable[(String, Array[Double])]
```

It now should be clear to you that the return of InferCVB0LabeledLDADocumentTopicDistributions cannot be used directly to feed EstimateLabeledLDAPerWordTopicDistributions.

I never used stanford nlp but this is by design how the api works, so you only need to convert your `scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[(String, Array[Double])]` into `Iterable[(String, scalala.collection.sparse.SparseArray[Double])]` before calling the function.

If you look at the scaladoc on how to do this conversion it's pretty simple. Inside the package stage, in package.scala I can read  `import scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable;`

So I know where to look, and in fact inside http://www.scalanlp.org/docs/core/data/#scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable you have a toIterable method which turns a LazyIterable into an Iterable, still you have to transform your internal array into a SparseArray

Again, I look into the package.scala for the stage package inside tmt and I see: `import scalala.collection.sparse.SparseArray;` And I look for scalala documentation :

http://www.scalanlp.org/docs/scalala/0.4.1-SNAPSHOT/#scalala.collection.sparse.SparseArray

It turns out that the constructors seems complicated to me, so it sounds much like I would have to look into the companion object for a factory method.  It turns out that the method I am looking for is there, and it's called apply like as usual in Scala.

```
def
apply [T] (values: T*)(implicit arg0: ClassManifest[T], arg1: DefaultArrayValue[T]): SparseArray[T]
```

By using this, you can write a function with the following signature:

```
def f: Array[Double] => SparseArray[Double]
```

Once this has done, you can turn your result of InferCVB0LabeledLDADocumentTopicDistributions into a non-lazy iterable of sparse Array with one line of code:

```
result.toIterable.map { case (name, values => (name, f(values)) }
```